# Adding color to the selected word in the vba formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In the below is it possible to add font color to **$BI$1** since i need to highlight that word. If add the font color am getting the #Feild error. Can someone pls guide me in this.
If i dont add **Font.Color = vbRed** , the formula is working fine.

```
=IF(BI2="no","no",IF(COUNTIFS(BI2:BL2,"yes")=4,$BI$1,IF(COUNTIFS(BK2:BL2,"no")>0,"no",IF(BJ2="no",$BI$1.Font.Color = vbRed,"NA"))))
```

Comment: No you can't do that in a formula.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you, the only way i can highlight a text is by writing the macro code in vb?

Comment: You may also use conditional formatting.

Comment: Coloring **a word** is different than coloring **a cell**... You cannot color **a word** (from more) if it comes like a result of a formula, in any way. You can change the whole cell font color of a cell, even if its text is the result of a formula. Making this aspect clear, what you really try accomplishing? Do you want automatically coloring the cell font when the formula result is changed to a specific string? If yes, you can do it using Conditional Formatting, as mentioned above, or using `Calculate` sheet event.